# get current picture folder of camera

Tags: android, camera

I have a small FileExplorer in my app and i want him to start in the folder, which is currently used by the defautl camera. Is there a way to get this path?
I tryed:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory (Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath());
```

But this do not returns "/mnt/sdcard/Pictures" and my Camera is storing in "mnt/sdcard/ext_sd/DCIM/100MEDIA/"

PS:
I do know how to start the camera with a specific folder for storing the pictures, that's not what i'm searching for,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String[] projection = new String[]{MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA,MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN,MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.MIME_TYPE};     
final Cursor cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,projection, null, null, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC"); 
if(cursor != null){
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    // you will find the last taken picture here
    // according to Bojan Radivojevic Bomber comment do not close the cursor (he is right ^^)
    //cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: What if there is no any photo been taken from camera ?

Comment: It will comes an error if a device didn't have external SD card installed.

Comment: this will not return only the images taken with the camera

Comment: I think you still need to close the cursor in a destructor method, like onDestroy() in an Activity or you can get cursor finalization error.