# Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES equivalent in pre API-8

Tags: android, api, camera

The `Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES` variable stores the path to image directory in Android 2.2 (API 8).

What is the most reasonable way to acquire this path in pre-8 versions?

It's probably (is it always in pre-8?) equivalent to the sdcard mountpoint.

Comment: Whats the best way of me appoaching my own related question to this? I have an error on Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES where it says this can not be resolved or is not a field.

Comment: is this because I am using android 2.1 (API 7) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The true answer: You can not know for certain.

The most probable answer: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM"`

If you know the last picture added to the device was from the camera, you can use the solution here: [get current picture folder of camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092691/get-current-picture-folder-of-camera)